# Django-rest-framework - fetching data from another server's DB

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I've implemented API using Django REST Framework that I use for my project which is a Flutter app.

*BUT, I want to add some data from another Server's database, can I do it in Django REST Framework, and then include those in my API ?

Comment: In your settings.py

Comment: follow https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/multi-db/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set multiple databases in settings.py file.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        ...
    },
    'other': {
        ...
    }
}
```

And you need to create another app `other` and define the models in models.py of the newly created project folder. Let's say, you defined a `Sport` model in `other` app.
Then in views.py file you can refer to this model.

```
from other.models import Sport

# in one of your api view
def SomeView(...):
    ...
    Sport.objects.using('other').create(...)
```

The main code is `using('...')`.

Note: You don't need to make migrations for the `other` app when you need to make migrations.